# Git default behavior in merging conflicting branches is just choosing the incoming change without highlighting, have to use --edit

Tags: git, git-bash

master branch contents

```
Hello 
Hi
Salut
```

other branch contents

```
Hi
Hey
Yo
```

clearly this should be a conflicting merge in which git should highlight current and incoming change but that's not the case, it says:

```
$ git merge tampering
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
 greetings.txt | 4 ++--
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

when i merge using `--edit` it highlights normally

```
$ git merge tampering --edit
Auto-merging greetings.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in greetings.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: A couple of things... what you've shared is not clearly a merge conflict.  Without sharing the common ancestor of the two branches its impossible to say that.  As for merging, git is going to do its best to make it so you DON'T have to do a manual merge (no one wants do have to handle a merge conflict).  It looks like you know how to perform a manual merge if you want to.  Do you have a specific question or just describing what you think to be incorrect behavior?

Comment: @heavyd i am describing what i think is an incorrect behaviour (or not that i expect) there is no common ancestor for both, master is the main branch and i made a branch out of it and changed the content as above so the 3 lines are changed, i switched to master and merged the other branch but instead of asking me to solve conflict manually (since i think that is a conflicting merge), it just replaced master content with other branch so now both branches just contain other branch content. I just want to know why it is merging that way when i am using default merge with no options.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes in that situation it is always going to take your branch over what is master because there are no conflicting changes (you just have one set of changes, your branch).   To get a manual merge you would need a conflicting change.  Try this:  start with the state you described as your "master" branch.  create a branch with your changes.  Now switch back to master and change "Salut" to "Good morning" save and add a commit to master.  Now try and merge, you should get a conflict because you conflicting changes in both branches.

Comment: If you always branch.. work on the the branch, then merge back to main/master you will not run into merge conflicts, git will always take the branch you're merging into main/master as the desired changes.